# Realm - react-native

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I'm developing an android application with React-Native that needs a database, I chose Realm.

The problem I'm having is that I do not have any database development knowledge, and I need a database that obviously saves user data such as email and password.

Can you recommend some tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

Using Realm requires little "database development knowledge" as we generally strive to make it as idiomatic and native to the language as possible.
There is documentation on the website: https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are not so many tutorials out there. You can see a tutorial in the documentations page: https://realm.io/docs/tutorials/realmtasks/

I suggest that you study the concept of NoSQL first. It will guide you through your learning process. After that, reading the official realm documentation helps. https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#introduction

I'm also kind of beginning to learn Realm myself and these things led me to developing my first app with Realm.

Hope it helps!